# python list append value depending on an if clause

Tags: python, list

I am new to Python, so apologize if the question is very simple.

I want to append a value to a list. However, I need to check if the value computed is less than `5000`.

If the value is less than `5000` then append the computed value, else append 5000. How can I do this?

e.g

```
mylist.append(a*list1[t]+b*list1[t+1])
```

My current approach:

```
if a*list1[t]+b*list1[t+1] < 5000:
    mylist.append(a*list1[t]+b*list1[t+1])
else:
    mylist.append(5000)
```

Can I do this in one line?

Comment: suggestion: use `var = a*list1[t]+b*list1[t+1]` so you don't need to write (and compute) this twice

Comment: `mylist.append(a*list1[t]+b*list1[t+1] if a*list1[t]+b*list1[t+1] < 5000 else 5000)`

Comment: Use `math.min`, like this: https://pastebin.com/RNkU6q8p

Comment: @Chris_Rands I think this question should be re-opened, it's not necessarily a duplicate of the one you linked to.

Comment: @nnyby Just regular min() will do it but ok reopening

Comment: oh woops - yeah it's just `min()`, there is no `math.min()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the builtin `min()` method.

Let `A = a*list1[t]` and `B = b*list1[t+1]`.

With your approach:

```
if A + B < 5000:
    mylist.append(A + B)
else:
    mylist.append(5000)
```

With `min()` approach:

```
mylist.append(min((A + B), 5000))
```

Comment: That works. As a followup. Can you suggest improvement to this code